# The excel call failed imagick

Tags: php, wordpress, imagick, imagemagick-convert, webp

I'm using webp express for wordpress. I want to convert images to webp with imagick but when I hover Imagick option, it says the excel call failed

[image: Screenshot of error]

How can I fix that?
If I enter `convert -version` in CPanel terminal, it says: `Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-68 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-06 https://imagemagick.org Copyright: © 1999-2019 ImageMagick Studio LLC License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP(3.1) Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo fontconfig freetype gslib jng jp2 jpeg lcms ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png ps rsvg tiff wmf x xml zlib`

Comment: Your ImageMagick is not installed with the webp delegate library. You need to install that. See https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/download

Comment: @fmw42 I need to install windows version in my CPanel?

Comment: Are you on Windows?  You have ImageMagick, it just does not have the webp delegate library installed into ImageMagick. You need to download webp and install it into ImageMagick.

Comment: @fmw42 I want to install ImageMagick on site, not on PC!

Comment: Your CPANEL says you already have ImageMagick installed. You need to install the webp delegate into ImageMagick on the server